# Cannot create sitemaps on nextjs with next-sitemap

Tags: javascript, next.js, xml-sitemap

I am trying to create dynamic sitemaps for my next-js site with [next-sitemap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-sitemap) but I'm running into an issue.

I have followed the docs and created the following

```
//pages/server-sitemap-index.xml/index.js
import axios from "axios";
import { getServerSideSitemapIndex } from "next-sitemap";

export const getServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {
  const res = await axios(`${process.env.API_ROOT}/books`);
  const { data } = res.data;
  const fields = data.map((item) => ({
    loc: `${process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL}/${item.slug}`,
    lastmod: item.updatedAt,
    priority: 0.7,
    changefreq: "daily",
  }));

  console.log({ fields });
  return getServerSideSitemapIndex(ctx, fields);
};

export default function SitemapIndex() {}
```

The `console.log` in the above code produces(as expected)

```
{
  fields: [
    {
      loc: 'http://localhost:3000/The-river-between-3pgkgy',
      lastmod: '2022-03-16T16:02:06.000Z',
      priority: 0.7,
      changefreq: 'daily'
    },
    {
      loc: 'http://localhost:3000/The-river-between-0tqwkgy',
      lastmod: '2022-03-16T16:02:06.000Z',
      priority: 0.7,
      changefreq: 'daily'
    },
    {
      loc: 'http://localhost:3000/The-river-between-tqwkgy',
      lastmod: '2022-03-16T16:02:06.000Z',
      priority: 0.7,
      changefreq: 'daily'
     }
  ]
}
```

However, `http://localhost:3000/server-sitemap-index.xml` produces:

```
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<sitemap>
<loc>[object Object]</loc>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>[object Object]</loc>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>[object Object]</loc>
</sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

The xml is not populated properly. I am using javascript, not typescript like the examples in the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-sitemap). Could this really be the issue?

Ps: All the other sitemaps(not dynamic) come out okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I found the problem.

I needed to import the correct module, `next-sitemap` has two APIs.

```
import { getServerSideSitemapIndex ,getServerSideSitemap } from "next-sitemap";
```

You need `getServerSideSitemap`.